# PHP update array with values and keys from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$a = [
    36 => 7,
    38 => 9,
    41 => 12,
    42 => 5
];

$b = [
    38 => 9,
    41 => 9,
    42 => 5
];
```

Array `a` has one extra `key[36]` and array `b` has a different value for `key[41]`.

How do i set a key in `a` to equal `0` if it is not in `b` and then how do i update a key in `a` if it has a different value in `b` and how do i add new keys to `a` if it is in `b` and not in `a`?

For now i've made this code:

```
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $b) && $value != $b[$key]){
        $a[$key] = $b[$key];
    } else{
        $a[$key] = 0;
    }
}

if($diff = array_diff_key($b, $a)){
    foreach($diff as $key => $value){
        $a[$key] = $value;
    }
}

ksort($a);
print_r($a);
```

And it works but i feel like there should be a much easier way :-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update a key in `a` if it has a different value in `b` and how do i add new keys to `a` if it is in `b` and not in `a`*

```
$a = array_replace($a, $b);
```

*Set a key in `a` equal to 0 if it is not in `b`*

```
foreach(array_diff_key($a, $b) as $k=>$v) {
   $a[$k] = 0;
}
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/1059166)

Comment: Why doesn't it work with indexes starting from 0? `array_merge()` would concatenate the arrays, but `array_replace()` does what you want.

Comment: @Barmar, my `keys` are actually shoe sizes :D that's why i don't start at 0 :D

Comment: I learned a new PHP function here. I've known about `array_merge`, but not `array_replace`.

Comment: @Barmar I use it in many cases. More than array_merge, I think